# Why Real human roles are missing in Smurfs The Lost Village (2017)?

Tags: the-smurfs, smurfs-the-lost-village

I already watched first 2 movies of Smurfs series, it contains non animation human roles  But this year's Smurfs The Lost Village (2017) released with full of animation excluding non animation roles, what is the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because for some reason unknown Sony decided to shelve the plans for "Smurfs 3" and instead do [an all-animation reboot](http://www.prnewswire.com/news-releases/sony-pictures-animation-unveils-updated-production-slate-249842691.html):

> Sony Pictures Animation has hired animation industry veteran Kelly
>   Asbury (*Shrek 2*, *Gnomeo & Juliet*) to direct an all new, fully
>   computer-animated film featuring the world's most popular blue
>   creatures.
>
> [...]
>
> Kelly Asbury, who was nominated for the Cannes Film Festival's Palme
>   d'Or for *Shrek 2*, offers, "I'm really excited about **taking the Smurfs
>   in a completely new fresh direction. We're not making a Smurfs 3 film.**
>   Our character designs and environments will be stylistically closer to
>   the original artwork created by Peyo. Our story will explore the
>   beginnings of the beloved little blue creatures in a fun full CG
>   animated comedy-adventure for every generation to enjoy."

There were [plans for a third Smurfs movie](http://variety.com/2012/film/news/sony-already-smurfing-smurfs-3-1118053808/); these even started shortly after production started on the second movie:

> Sony Pictures Animation and Columbia Pictures are feeling confident in
>   their upcoming “Smurfs” sequel, as **the studios are already developing
>   a script for “Smurfs 3”** with scribes Karey Kirkpatrick and Chris
>   Poche, sources tell Variety.

It was [supposed to contain an origin story](http://www.comingsoon.net/movies/news/106456-exclusive-the-smurfs-3-will-include-an-origin-story):

> While at the Paris Hotel in Las Vegas to talk to the actors about the
>   upcoming The Smurfs 2, ComingSoon.net questioned Gargamel’s origins to
>   which Azaria revealed, I hear that the third movie, if there is one,
>   might actually **deal with the genuine origin of how all these
>   characters ran into each other way back when**.